# Apache's ErrorDocument directive for asp/IIS?

Tags: .htaccess, iis, asp-classic

now i saw a very good php script and i rewrite it to asp
the script here:[Fantastic Animation PHP/CSS/jQuery Error pages](http://bit.ly/4pIMVQ)
but know iam in big problem
how i can use .htaccess in asp
see how it work

```
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?code=500
```

can i use .htaccess in asp
please tell me because iam newbie in it
because know i convery error.php to error.asp

Answer (score 2):

`.htaccess` is a web server thing (primarily Apache), not a PHP or ASP thing. If you have your system set up that Apache serves ASP pages (passing through to IIS or using another ASP interpreter), sure, you can use `.htaccess` with it. But if you're using IIS directly, IIS has [its own mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525983.aspx) for doing things like mapping error pages and such.